# Ruby on Rails OOP not working as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm writing a module to handle payment within our website.

```
# lib/payment/payment.rb
module Payment
  class Payment
    # some payment handling
  end
end
```

And I want to separate out the logic that determines the amount due. We'll just say that we're paying for a `Car` as an example.

Now, I was under the impression that this would work:

```
# lib/payment/car.rb
module Payment
  class Car < Payment
    # builds amount for cars
  end
 end
```

But even in the Payment module, with Payment::Payment defined, it is is throwing:

```
TypeError: superclass must be a Class (Module given)
```

I'm know that this resolves the issue:

```
class Payment::Car < Payment::Payment
  # stuff
end
```

But I'm curious as to why my solution wasn't working.

Comment: Could it be that `lib/payment/payment.rb` needs to be `lib/payment.rb` and keep the rest in the `lib/payment` folder?

Comment: Nope... I'm really curious as to what I am missing.

Comment: Okay, so it definitely has to do with naming both module and class Payment. All suggestions and comments are appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you exactly nailed it in your comment. Naming both the module and class `Payment` is the problem.

When you have

```
module Payment
  class Car < Payment
  end
end
```

autoload tries (when loading `Car`) to load `Payment`. The first Constant it comes across in the tree with the name `Payment` is a module, not a class. It doesn't know you're trying to load a class called `Payment` - so it tries to use the module `Payment`. That's why you get the error you get.

When you do

```
Payment::Car < Payment::Payment
```

You're explicitley saying you want a class `Payment` located in a module `Payment`, so now autoload is able to load the correct Constant.

As a follow-on thought, it seems conceptually weird to have `Car` inherit from `Payment`. Technically, it works. But it doesn't reflect the real world. To enable classes with payment behaviors, you may want to go the composition route. So, make a module something like:

```
module Payments
  module PaymentClassMethods
    def some_method
    end
    def some_other_method
    end
  end
end
```

Then do

```
module Payments
  class Car
    extend PaymentClassMethods
  end
end
```

Now, `Car` doesn't inherit from `Payment`, but still has the payment behaviors.

If you also want `Car` to get instance methods, you could do something like:

```
module Payments
  module PaymentClassMethods
    def some_class_method
    end
    def some_other_class_method
    end
  end
  module PaymentInstanceMethods
    def some_instance_method
    end
    def some_other_instance_method
    end
  end
end

module Payments
  class Car
    include PaymentInstanceMethods
    extend PaymentClassMethods
  end
end
```

If you're doing this a lot, you may want to re-open the `Car` class so you could just say `include PaymentMethods` and get both the class and instance methods. But, that's a bit of a different topic.

Also, if you're including (or extending) methods that interact with models other than `Car`, then I'd suggest you consider creating a service object. IMO, models should know very little about one another. If you're `Car` model ends up knowing a lot about other models, then you could end up with some tight coupling - which can be a problem if you start monkeying with your `Car` model. Again, topic for a separate discussion. But, hopefully the thought helps.

Comment: Have some more thoughts for you on this, but am heading to church. Back at you later.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks you it is much appreciated. I opted to call the module Payments as it only holds classes that are inherited from Payment.

Comment: Oh snap that's cool! I don't know that it quite fits my situation, but reading made me recall dozens of times where this would of been perfect! Excellent answer sir!

Comment: I had to change my perspective on the problem a little, but you're follow up was the right solution for me! Instead of passing a Rails model to a payment module, I was able to get the Rails model to include and extend payment features! Brilliant!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it seems like naming a both a module and a class the same thing complicates things.

```
module A
  class B
  end

  class C < B
  end
end

A::C.superclass
=> A::B
```

But if we name the class the same as the module:

```
module A
  class A
  end

  class B < A
  end
end

TypeError: superclass mismatch for class B
```

If anyone has faced this sort of thing or has any comments or suggestions, feel free to share!